# Merge Sort Function in Python

Tags: python, sorting, merge

I am having trouble with some code in Python:

```
def sort(number_list):
    if len(number_list <= 1):
        return number_list
    front_list = []
    back_list = []
    counter = 0
    half = len(number_list)//2
    for x in number_list:
        if counter < half:
            front_list.append(x)
            counter += 1
        else:
            back_list.append(x)

    front_list = sort(front_list)
    back_list = sort(back_list)
    print(front_list)
    print(back_list)
    return merge(front_list, back_list)

def merge(front_list, back_list):
    output = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    lenght1 = len(front_list)
    length2 = len(back_list)
    while i < lenght1 or j < length2:
        if i < lenght1 and j < length2:
            if front_list[i] <= back_list[j]:
                output += [front_list[i]]
                i = i + 1
            else:
                output += [back_list[j]]
                j = j + 1
        elif i < front_list:
            output += [front_list[i]]
            i = i+1
        else:
            output += [back_list[j]]
            j = j+1
    return output
```

I keep getting the type error unorderable types: list() <= int()
Can someone let me know where I am going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Which line of code produces the type error?

Comment: elif i < front_list:

Comment: Your are also going to get an IndexError, look at the pseudocode here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: Trying to follow the spelling with `lenght1` and `length2` makes me feel like I can't read.

Comment: You might also want to look into python's slicing syntax to replace the loops where you loop append, e.g. `front_list, back_list = number_list[:half], number_list[half:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement in the `sort()` function should be as follows:

```
if len(number_list) <= 1:
    return number_list
```

Additionally, in `merge()`

```
elif i < front_list:
```

should be

```
elif i < lenght1:
```

Comment: You need to also change: `elif i < front_list:` to `elif i < lenght1:` (including the spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, you can simplify your logic somehwat, both in terms of using python slicing and slightly changing the logic of merge:

```
def sort(number_list):
    if len(number_list) <= 1:
        return number_list
    half = len(number_list)//2
    front_list = sort(number_list[:half])
    back_list = sort(number_list[half:])
    print(front_list)
    print(back_list)
    return merge(front_list, back_list)

def merge(front_list, back_list):
    output = []
    j = 0
    for i in range(front_list):
        while j < len(back_list) and front_list[i] > back_list[j]:
            output.append(back_list[j])
            j += 1
        output.append(front_list[i])
    for x in range(j, len(back_list)):
        output.append(back_list[x])
    return output
```